# Why does the Laravel Lighthouse @rename directive not work for me?

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I have this GraphQL query:

```
mutation CreateBudget(
  $revenue: Float!,
  $hours: Int!,
  $projectId: Int!,
) {
  createBudget(
    revenue: $revenue,
    hours: $hours,
    projectId: $projectId,
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

For best practices, I want to use camelcase here, but snake_case in my database. The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `budgets` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `revenue` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `hours` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `budgets_project_id_foreign` (`project_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `budgets_project_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I use [Lighthouse's @rename directive](https://lighthouse-php.com/4.4/api-reference/directives.html#rename) in order to convert between the casings. When running the query however, when submitting my query, some part of the code doesn't seem to recognise the project id, resulting in the following SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'project_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `budgets` (`revenue`, `hours`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1200, 12, 2019-12-03 09:12:13, 2019-12-03 09:12:13))
```

The variables sent are

```
variables: {
    revenue: 1200,
    hours: 12,
    projectId: 1
}
```

This is how my schema.graphql looks, using the @rename directive on the Budget type:

```
type Budget {
  id: ID!
  revenue: Float!
  hours: Int!
  projectId: Int! @rename(attribute: "project_id")
  project: Project! @belongsTo
  created_at: DateTime
  updated_at: DateTime
}

type Mutation {
    createBudget(
        revenue: Float!
        hours: Int!
        projectId: Int!
    ): Budget @create(model: "App\\Models\\Budget\\Budget")
}
```

I must have overlooked something simple, but I can't seem to spot it. Anybody want to give it a shot?

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but is `project_id` fillable in the model?

Comment: project_id is fillable indeed, as are all the other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the rename directive on mutations is supported as of version 4.7 and needs an extra declaration of the rename directive on the property in the mutation.

Your mutation should look like this:

```
type Mutation {
    createBudget(
        revenue: Float!
        hours: Int!
        projectId: Int! @rename(attribute: "project_id")
    ): Budget @create(model: "App\\Models\\Budget\\Budget")
}
```

Comment: You are wrong in both cases. Using the rename directive on the mutation doesn't work either. Furthermore, the [docs mention @rename in version 2.6](https://lighthouse-php.com/2.6/api-reference/directives.html#rename) already, so I don't think I'd need to be using master. I'm using v4.6 by the way.

Comment: Yes, `@rename` directive exists long time ago, but just few days ago it was changed to also work with Inputs (before it just worked in Type Fields). See PR: https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/pull/1062

Comment: That wouldn't change anything, since I'm defining my @rename on a Type and not on an Input.

Comment: Apparently declaring the rename directive on a type only affects queries and not mutations. Using the rename directive again on the mutation directly will solve this, but only as of v4.7 (which was released only yesterday). I find this double declaration weird however and [submitted an issue](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/1073#issuecomment-562052134)